# Diagonalizing a power set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> $S$ be any non-empty set, $2^S$ denote the power set of $S$. Let $f$
>   be a function from $S$ to $2^S$, where for each $x \in S$, $f(x)
>  \subseteq S$. Also, $f$ is injective. Show that $f$ cannot be
>   surjective.

I was consider using a diagonalization argument. But have trouble constructing a set $T$ not present in the domain of $f(x)$. How should I make the $T$?

Comment: If $S$ is finite, then there is an easy argument to show that the cardinality of $2^{S}$ is strictly bigger than the cardinality of $S$... so no function from $S$ to $2^{S}$ can be surjective.  It is also true that the cardinality of $2^{S}$ is strictly bigger than the cardinality of $S$ if $S$ is infinite, but this is much harder to show.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for pointing out the mistake :). It is fixed now.

Comment: Should that be "... where for each $x \in S, f(x) \subseteq S$"?

Comment: @TravisJ In a sense, the proof by diagonalization (which works for the finite case as well as the infinite case) is simpler than arguments along the lines you propose, when you get down to the set-theoretic details.

Comment: $f(x)$ would not necessarily _have_ a domain. $\:$ (Also, "constructing a set $T$ not present $\hspace{1.31 in}$ in the domain of" $\hspace{.02 in}f$ is not relevant here. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I think that Cantor cracked this one a few years back.

Answer (score 4):

The element $$\{x\in S\mid x\notin f(x)\}\in 2^S$$ is not in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

The set provided by Arthur, let us call it $A$, does the job. It took me a while until I understood why it works.

Example:
$$
S = \{ 0, 1 \} \\
2^S = \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}
$$
Then we have only two values to assign, $f$ was assumed injective, so they need to be different. We choose
\begin{align}
f(0) &= \emptyset \\
f(1) &= \{0, 1 \} 
\end{align}
Then $A$ calculates to
$$
A = \{ x \in S \,|\, x \not\in f(x) \} = \{ 0 \} \in 2^S
$$
and indeed $A \not\in f(S)$.

If this was not the case then there would exist a $x^*\in S$ with
$f(x^*) = A$.

It gets interesting, once we want to decide the membership of $x^*$ in $A$.

1. Assuming $x^* \in A$, but
   $$
   x^* \in A = f(x^*)
   $$
   and $A$ is selected from elements $x\in S$ with $x \notin f(x)$, this is not possible.
2. The only other possibility
   $x^* \notin A$
   would mean $x^* \notin f(x^*)$ which would mean $x^*\in A$, which can not be.

This means there is no such $x^*$, $A$ is selected such that it is outside $f(S)$.